# Getting success response from AWS SNS but SMS not delivered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am writing a simple program to send SMS using SNS service using the Javascript client.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS({
  region : 'ap-southeast-1',
  accessKeyId: '',
  secretAccessKey: ''
});
sns.publish({
      Message : "Test message",
      PhoneNumber : "Test number"
    }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
          console.log("Error - " + err);

        }
        else {
          console.log('Success - ');
          console.log(data);

        }

    });
```

I get a success and the data looks like

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '3b4e8c82-976c-55da-b1fa-dcd9ddc7254d' },
  MessageId: '47a38cbe-2047-5056-a615-dce56aecc0c1' }
```

However, the SMS does not get delivered.

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you tried with aws console?

Comment: @Abdul Manaf - Yes.

Comment: if it is working or not ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf Sorry, I was not clear. Using AWS console works fine. I receive an SMS.

Comment: @AbdulManaf i have same issue i tried aws console but it also show message id but did not send sms to phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The messages started getting delivered after 24th for fresh requests. The metrics dashboard is showing the data a day stale. On the dashboard It correctly showed that all the SMS deliveries had failed on 21st September, inspite of a positive response from API. This is making me reconsider my decision of using SNS for SMS.

Thanks all who helped.

Comment: I am adding this comment in case it helps anyone else. 

As of this writing, in javascript sdk, if you do not prefix your phone number with '+1' you will get a success for AWS but the message will not be sent.

Once, I added the plus it started working.

Thanks for the comment about the console in the thread...it got me thinking about the formatting of the phone number in that use case.

Comment: @E.Maggini your comment cleared this issue up for me thank you! So simple but I couldn't find any information anywhere that suggested this. I don't think the AWSJavaScriptSDK docs for SNS specify that it needs to be in the format of '+1' but it should!

Comment: @ E. Maggini, just confirming this to still be the case 2021

Answer (score 2):

Setting up MessageAttributes for SMSTypes works for me.

> {'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': 'Promotional'}}

for MessageAttributes in publish function. Your publish function will look like

> client.publish(PhoneNumber="YOUR_NUMBER",Message="YOUR_MESSAGE",MessageAttributes={'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': 'Transactional'}})

By default, SMSType will be Promotional because of this message won't go on DND numbers.

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045868/error-sending-a-sms-with-amazon-sns-and-python-and-boto3)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using SNS SMS where I was receiving the message_id back from AWS but not getting the delivered text message.

I solved the issue after checking that the region in my api call was set to the same region as my origination number.

Hopefully saving someone else from the same headache.

Answer (score -1):

We need to specify more SNS parameters.

Documentation pages that might help:

- Pushing to SNS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property

try this code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS({
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
});


var params = {
    Message: 'Test message',
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: 'Test number'
};
sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log("error-> " + err + "-" + number + "-" + JSON.stringify(params)); // an error occurred
    else console.log("SMS to " + number + " successfull " + JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
});
```

You got output like this

```
{"ResponseMetadata":"RequestId":"2bb91f08-3ef0-5e55-8219-4645645"},"MessageId":"943a1224-042c-576c-936e-sfsdf34535"} {"Message":"hai manaf...r u happy","MessageStructure":"string","PhoneNumber":"+9197********"}.
```

But i don't get SMS to my DND activated phone number. i still research this issue.

Comment: Would you please let me know the ones that I have missed. I can see that SNS is highly configurable, but I do not see any mandatory fields that I have missed.

Comment: please reply the status

Comment: I tried your code. The same result. No SMS. Looks like the code is not the problem. Something else is going wrong. I will continue investigating. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you figure out solution for DND activated numbers?, I set up message attributes as transnational but still messages are not delivering.

Answer (score -1):

set your message type as "Transactional" it will work

Answer (score -2):

What is your version of aws-sdk?
Try update the newest one.

Comment: It is the latest version available on NPM