# ERROR sending a SMS with Amazon SNS and Python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, boto3

The documentation suggests to use the script below but I can't seem to figure out why im getting an error message.

This what im using so far:

```
sns = boto3.client('sns', region_name='eu-west-1')
sns.publish(
  PhoneNumber='+5521981554856',
  Message='hi there',
  MessageAttributes={
                        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
                                                     'DataType': 'String',
                                                     'StringValue': 'MySenderID'   
}    
}   
)
```

does anyone knows why im getting the error msg below?

```
raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "PhoneNumber", must be one of: TopicArn,TargetArn, Message, Subject, MessageStructure, MessageAttributes
```

why "PhoneNumber " is presenting such an awkward behaviour?

Comment: what happens when you remove the message attributes? It should work fine.                                                   sns.publish(PhoneNumber='+5521981554856',Message='hi there')

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the following code:

```
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns')
smsattrs = {
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': { 'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': 'TestSender' },
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': { 'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': 'Transactional'}
}
sns.publish(
    PhoneNumber = '+35840xxxxxxx',
    Message = 'Hello world!',
    MessageAttributes = smsattrs
)
```

The biggest difference I see is that you have not set `AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType`.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that PhoneNumber is supported.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html

Sadly, that's just copy-paste from official AWS documentation.

If you look at source code, you'll see that Boto3 expects either TargetArn or TopicArn:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/master/boto3/data/sns/2010-03-31/resources-1.json

```
"Publish": {
      "request": {
        "operation": "Publish",
        "params": [
          { "target": "TopicArn", "source": "identifier", "name": "Arn" }
        ]
      }
    },
```

...

```
"Publish": {
          "request": {
            "operation": "Publish",
            "params": [
              { "target": "TargetArn", "source": "identifier", "name": "Arn" }
            ]
          }
        },
```

So I guess you have to patch Boto3 yourself or file an issue on GitHub.