# SMS text not received but no errors from AWS/Lamda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sms, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Migrating and EC2 LAMP stack into serverless architecture with Lambda handling the SMS text messages.
My PHP code also works fine and from the console:

```
aws sns publish --phone-number 0044xxxxxxxxxx --message boo --region eu-west-1
```

Also works

When I run the NodeJS in Lambda from the command line I get  "Status": 202 but no text.

When I run that same code from the TEST button in the Inline Code Editor on AWS I get "Successful", clean logs but no text..

The code failing is:

```
// dependencies
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
var params = {
   MessageStructure: 'string',
   PhoneNumber: '0044xxxxxxxxxx',
   Message:'An error occurred'

};
sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
   console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   context.done(err, 'Finished with Errors!');  
   return;
}
else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
  context.done(null,'finished');
};
```

This is also code I got from another question in SO which was shown to work for another user.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Many thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you might want to look into:

You'll need to make sure you're using either Node.js runtime v6.10 or v4.3. (Node v0.10.42 is currently marked as deprecated. AWS recommends migrating existing functions to the newer Node.js runtime versions as soon as possible)

The IAM role for your lambda function needs to have an *Allow* rule for the `sns:Publish` action.

AWS recommends that specify the phone number using the E.164 format. For example: +44xxxxxxxxxx. ([more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html))

Also, AWS **strongly** recommends updating any use of the `context` method and replacing it with the `callback` approach ([more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html)). For example:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: "2010-03-31"});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const params = {
    PhoneNumber: "+44xxxxxxxxxx", // E.164 format.
    Message: "STRING_VALUE",
    MessageStructure: "STRING_VALUE"
  }
  sns.publish(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error ${err.message}`);
      callback(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success");
      callback(null, data); // callback instead of context.
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this Khalid, got me to the next issue of modifying my role. Appreciate your helps and can now send texts from Lambda.

Comment: Hi @Khalid T, How to get CloudWatch logs with the help of request-id and message-id. can you explain how to do this?

Comment: @VishalSharma: You could create a [CloudWatch Subscription Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) that sends log data to a Lambda function, which stores the data into a database table or S3 bucket from which you can query by message ID.

Comment: Hi @KhalidT. I am used the same process to send the message to the end client. but MessageId & RequestId have received . but how to check message status is a success  or not by using nodejs AWS-SDK. can you help me regarding this issue

Comment: @VishalSharma: This better be a new question because it's difficult to answer in a comment but the basic idea is that the two log groups that capture the delivery status are *sns/{REGION}/{ACCOUNT_NO}/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber* and *sns/{REGION}/{ACCOUNT_NO}/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber/Failure*. So, having a lambda function (node.js runtime or whatever) that receives log data from the CloudWatch Logs subscription filter and updates your DDB or S3 with the event details would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answer [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034691/4374362), it worked for me. By default the message type is set as Promotional and you have to override it as transactional.